# how to limit show records in dropdownlist Access 2007

Tags: database, ms-access

I showed the data records in a datasheet to an Access 2007 form

some fields are dropdownlist so it show the field as it is dropdownlist but i want it to be a normal field and shows just the value

Comment: Don't overwrite your question with a new question. Ask a new one.

Comment: it's just because i can"t post 2 question in the same time ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For forms in design mode right click on combobox, Change To... -> Text Box

For tables click on field in design mode, select Lookup tab and change Display Control to Text Box

Comment: You completely changed the question. If you have another question, please create new question, do not edit existing one. Question is not clear anyway

Comment: because its impossible to post 2 question .. i should waiting for 4 days ..

Comment: @JamilaAmallou: That system is in place to prevent lots of bad questions. You need to work on your question quality. See [help]

Comment: it's not about my question quality its about my english not good so i can't expain very well my question , at th first my question was in French and they tell me that the question must be in english ..